# Finding the Key used to Encrypt

Tags: encryption, xor

I have this pseudo code:

```
for i = 0 ... P.length
    C[i] = P[i] XOR K[i%K];
    K[i%k] = ( K[i%k] +P[i] ) mod 64;
```

Where P is a plain text, C is the encrypted text, K is a key and k denotes the length of the key K (note the caps is different for k and K).

Please note that this IS a homework but it ain't mine, I'm just rather curious on how to solve it since I've always liked encryption subjects.

The task here is to deduce the plain text P if you are given C and you know the following about the key.

> The key is chosen as a random word from [this TWL Word List](http://www.isc.ro/lists/twl064.html). A random number between 0 and 999 is appended to the end of the chose word. With probability 0.5 the first character was capitalized. Lowercase 'o' is then converted to '0' (zero) with probability 0.5 for each 'o'. Similarly, each lowercase 'l' (ell) is converted to '1' (one), each 'e' to '3', each 's' to '5', and each 't' to '7', all with probability 0.5.

The program is required to take less than 10 seconds and consume less than 1 GB of memory. The class given this problem have mid-range laptops so I'd take those 10 seconds seriously (although, since I'm not really solving a homework I don't have time limitations).

What would be a good way to approach this problem? 'Cause it doesn't seem as if brute force is going to be of any use here.

**P.S.** *IF* "%" is modular division... then that does "mod" do?

**Edit:**
Plain text P is a random text taken from the Wikipedia in which all characters that aren't letters or numbers are stripped out (including spaces) I'm almost certain that each character is matched against [a-zA-Z0-9] and removed if doesn't match.

**Edit 2:**
[This .pdf](http://oxbowc.webs.com/Problem_statement.pdf) will probably help clarify. In there you will find examples of P outputs and the Key.

Comment: I assume the `mod` and `%` mean the same thing, just that the professor wanted to keep it _looking_ simple.

Comment: The mod 64 is weird. And if I understand you correctly, the length of the key will be 5 for sure? (the list has only 4 letter words, and we add a number). The key and plaintext are ASCII encoded, or what?

Comment: On second thought, the 64 suggests that maybe the OP meant an encoding of capitals A-Z as 0-25, a-z as 26-61, and the digits plus maybe 2 other characters as the last 2 (base64 style), or some variation of this, and that maybe the cipher text is also encoded this way. Please clarify.

Comment: @Henno: The key can be in between 5 and 8 letters. The number appended is between 0 and 999. As to mod 64 I have no idea.

Comment: Knowing the encoding is essential. Try to find out!

Comment: Mod and "%" is the same thing. Just FYI the 64 was a calculated number taking the amount of letters and numbers available but I don't think this is rather important.

Comment: It is, believe me. How can you write a program to accept the input if you don't know the format? Cryptanalysis might abuse illegal characters etc. So you **have** to know the alphabets/encodings for plaintext, key and ciphertext.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, please look at the edits.

Comment: But is the encoding a=0,b=1 etc, or A=0,B=1, or ASCII? If ASCII, then stripping symbols would not be necessary. If not, we need 2 more symbols (maybe space as well?) to get 64. And are all alphabets the same, plain,cipher and key?

Comment: Letters use their ASCII value.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF, which indeed shows a numeric coding, as I suggested, not ASCII. The ciphertext is then binary, it seems, but in what "units"? There were no examples of ciphertext in the downloads. 0 could appear there, e.g., and how is this represented (not as a-zA-Z0-9)? Is the ciphertext a sequence of binary bytes, that just happen to represent values <64?

Comment: The info on the pdf is as much as I got...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  was one of the students who had to solve this problem and I found the answer, my score was 0.934 of 1, which I think it's nice for the first try. Anyway, I'm not gonna post my code here 'cause I believe if you really want to solve something you have to fight for it (I know, I know), but I can give you a few tips on how to solve it.
One thing you may notice while working on this problem, is that there's a characteristic that appears when the keylength of the Key is equal to the keylength of the key you are trying to use to decrypt the text, you will find words like "that" "and" "in" I mean the most common words you find in an English text. If you already know the length of the key you can start to look for it. Remember that there are rules for the construction of the key, if you use those rules, you don't even have to use the TWL WORD LIST. Think about it a little bit and you will see that the whole problems is just a multiplication and substitution problem (my approach at least).
I hope this tips can help someone that has to do this program, if you have another question you can ask me ;) I`ll try to help you out.